# Matplotlib's matshow not aligned with grid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 6x6 matrix that represents a grid. On part of that grid I have a smaller grid (3x3) represented below:

```
In [65]:

arr = np.zeros((6,6))
arr[0:3, 0:3] = 1
arr
Out[65]:
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I wish to plot this, but matplotlib misalignes it, as you can see below. The red square is supposed to cover the area from 0 to 3 on both the horizontal and vertical axis.

```
In [88]:

plt.matshow(arr)
plt.grid()
```

[image]

How do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to fix?  the alignment of the dashed lines?

Comment: @jedwards: yes. The red region should start at zero and end at 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish, you can use:

```
matshow(arr, extent=[0, 6, 0, 6])
```

However, the standard behaviour is as expected: the pixel centred at (0, 0) has the value of element (0, 0).

Answer (score 9):

You could use major ticks for labels and minor ticks for the grid.

Consider:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((6,6))
arr[0:3, 0:3] = 1

plt.matshow(arr)

# This is very hack-ish
plt.gca().set_xticks([x - 0.5 for x in plt.gca().get_xticks()][1:], minor='true')
plt.gca().set_yticks([y - 0.5 for y in plt.gca().get_yticks()][1:], minor='true')
plt.grid(which='minor')

plt.show()
```

Which shows:

[image: Output]

The trick is just these 2 lines:

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(..., minor='true')
plt.grid(which='minor')
```